# Appending, using '+', a String vs a char

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, tostring

Whenever I tried to generated `toString()` method with IntelliJ IDEA, I see

```java
return ... +
        ", some='" + '\'' + // some is an String field
        '}';
```

Does it make any significant performance gain against following signature?

```java
return ... +
        ", some='" + "'" +
        "}";
```

Or is it just a template and means nothing?

Comment: The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode. Instead use Unicode code point integer numbers.

Comment: Code point numbers can't represent everything in unicode that a user would consider a character either. it's not really relavent here though....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is possibly a small performance difference in concatenating a `char` versus a `String`.

- In the `char` case, the concatenation will most likely just be an append of a `char` to a `StringBuilder`.
- In the `String` case, a naive implementation would entail a loop to copy all of the characters in the `String`.  Also, there is an extra level of indirection, possibly two `null` check, and a possible array bounds check when accessing the string's character (or byte) array.

HOWEVER

1. While the performance difference (if you measured it) may be significant in a micro-benchmark for that `toString()` method, it is *typically* going to be insignificant in the context of a real applications.

   In general, it is not worthwhile use of a programmer's time to focus on performance at this level of detail.  The significant performance issues are likely to be in other areas.  A good strategy is to use a benchmark, profile, optimize methodology ... once you have a code that is feature complete and passing tests.
2. There are plans to introduce JIT "smarts" to optimize String concatenation sequences; see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280.

   I am not sure if this particular case is optimized (yet) in the latest Java JIT compilers.  But it is clearly on the cards that the optimization will be added.